# Как вывести число с ведущими нулями?

Tags: python

Работа обычного инкремента понятна

```
i=0
while true
    i++
    print i
```

выводит 1,2,3 и тд это понятно

Как сделать инкремент который будет состоять из двух, трех ... цифр с ведущими нулями?

```
001
002
003
```

Comment: В дополнение к ответам ещё советую посмотреть функцию printf/sprintf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i=1
while i<4: 
    print(str(i).zfill(3)) # zfill - zero fill, цифра - количество ведущих нулей
    i +=1                  # минус длина строковой переменной
```

Получим

```
001
002
003
```

Answer (score 1):

```
i = 0
while i<12:
    i += 1
    print("{:0>3}".format(i))


001
002
003
004
...
```