# Как выводимому значению, например 9:5, придать вид времени, чтобы вышло 09:05

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задачка из самого начала - блок Ввод-вывод (ни циклов, ни условных операторов ничего кроме Ввода-вывода и форматирования еще не проходили).
Условие задачи такое:
*

> Сегодня в NN часов MM минут хозяин магазина заказал доставку нового
> товара. Оператор сказал, что продукты доставят через TT минут. Сколько
> будет времени на электронных часах, когда привезут долгожданные
> продукты?
>   Формат ввода
>  В первой строке записано натуральное число N(0≤N<24).  
> Во второй строке записано натуральное число M (0≤M<60).
>   В
> третьей строке записано натуральное число T (0≤T<10в9й степени).
> Формат вывода: Одна строка, представляющая циферблат электронных часов.

- 

Я написал код, технически все работает. Осталось привести к виду с нулями перед часами и минутами, когда это нужно. UPD - добавил другой вывод. Нули появились, все работает, НО! задачник пишет решение не верно((

```
min_d = 1440
min_h = 60  
# прошло с начала дня часов
hours = int(input())
# прошло с начала дня минут
minutes = int(input())
# сколько минут ждать
time_waiting = int(input())
# сколько всего прошло минут с начала дня на момент звонка
min_now = hours * min_h + minutes 
# сколько будет минут с начала суток когда привезут продукты
dlvr_min = min_now + time_waiting
d = dlvr_min / min_d
# вычитаем лишние сутки, чтобы часов было не больше 24
d1 = dlvr_min - min_d * int(d)
h = int(d1 / min_h)
m = d1 - h * min_h
print(str(h).zfill(2)+':'+str(m).zfill(2))
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вывести число с ведущими нулями?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/912197/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d1%81-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d0%bc%d0%b8)

Comment: Благодарю, но решение не может содержать циклов, я этого не могу знать исходя из пройденной темы. https://academy.yandex.ru/handbook/python/article/vvod-i-vyvod-dannykh-operatsii-s-chislami-strokami-formatirovaniye

Comment: @СергейВодолагин цикл там только от кода в вопросе. Нужно смотреть на print

Comment: @insolor круто, возьму на заметку! Код работает корректно, но задачник Яндекса говорит, что решение неверное((

Comment: Ну может там прямо код проверяют, и требуют через f-строку. Тогда примерно как у вас было только форматирование через `f"{h:0>2}:{m:0>2}"` (по аналогии со вторым ответом по ссылке в первом комментарии)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@insolor Благодарю! решением оказалось записать через f-строку как в коментарии.

```
print(f"{h:0>2}:{m:0>2}")
```